# Why do two identical zips on Linux have different md5 sum values?

Tags: linux, zip, md5

I created these two zip files about 24 hours apart.

```
$ ls -l /tmp/*.zip
-rw-rw-r-- 1 scott scott 1401289 Mar 21 20:11 /tmp/inc1.zip
-rw-rw-r-- 1 scott scott 1401289 Mar 22 19:29 /tmp/inc2.zip
```

You can see they're the same size, because the directory being zipped hasn't changed.

However, when I run md5sum on them, I get different results.

```
$ md5sum /tmp/inc*
95b1c0b32cc24a5554769797e032ec6e  /tmp/inc1.zip
80765ac3fc7f488243bdc1c06902e33c  /tmp/inc2.zip
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably something simple like the mtime/atime on file(s) inside the .zip changed since the first one was created .

`zdiff` and `bzdiff` exist to diff-compare gzip and bzip2 compressed files, respectively, however no such native utility exists for zip files AFAIK. You could try something like [diffzips.pl](http://zarb.org/~gc/html/diffzips.html)

Comment: I'll bet you it's the atime.  That's frustrating, since the files themselves are the same.

Comment: Both cmp and diff show them as different.  I hadn't considered file attributes - I'll bet that's it.